# openshift ingress router has been stopped. Can you recover?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, haproxy, okd, ingress-controller

The default router pod was stopped while working on Taints and Tolerations.

I am unable to log in.

Can I change node config before login?

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us which version of openshift you use `oc version`. the `oc` command connects to the api sever which implies that the configuration is possible via cli if the webconsole is not reachable.

Comment: oc version(Client Version): 4.10.14

Answer (score 0):

You can login via cli command as documented [Logging in to the OpenShift CLI](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/cli_reference/openshift_cli/getting-started-cli.html#cli-logging-in_cli-developer-commands)

In short

```
oc login <CLUSTER_API_NAME>:6443 -u <YOUR_USER>
```

Comment: thank you. ```The connection to the server oauth-openshift.apps.ocp.t.[domain] was refused - did you specify the right host or port?```

Comment: how does the full `oc login` command looks like?

Comment: ```
oc login --server=https://api.ocp.[domain]:6443
or
oc login https://api.ocp.[domain]:6443 -u devadmin
```

Comment: can you connect to the server via curl? `curl -v https://api.ocp.[domain]:6443`

Comment: Thank you. 
Deleting other information in the kubeconfig file succeeded.

Comment: Thank you for being with us.

Answer (score 0):

It succeeded by removing everything except admin from the context in the kubeconfig file.